# Possible to execute Python bytecode from a script?

Tags: python-3.x, cpython

Say I have a running CPython session,

Is there a way to run the data (`bytes`) from a `pyc` file directly?
*(without having the data on-disk necessarily, and without having to write a temporary pyc file)*

Example script to show a simple use-case:

```
if foo:
    # Intentionally ambiguous, since the data source
    # is a detail and answers shouldn't depend this detail.
    data = read_data_from_somewhere()
else:
    data = open("bar.pyc", 'rb').read()

assert(type(data) is bytes)

code = bytes_to_code(data)

# call a method from the loaded code
code.call_function()
```

---

Exact use isn't important, but generating code dynamically and copying over a network to execute is one use-case (for the purpose of thinking about this question).

---

Here are some example use-cases, which made me curious to know how this can be done:

- Checking Python scripts for malicious code.
  *If a single command can access a larger body of code hidden in binary data, what would that command look like?*
- Dynamically generate code and cache it for re-use (not necessarily on disk, could use a data-base for example).
- Ability to send pre-compiled byte-code to a process, *control an application which embeds Python for eg*.

Comment: Why send bytecode at all instead of source? You have to byte-compile it somewhere, and if you do it on the transmitting side, debugging the far side will be a bitch. Also, a quick look at my python experiment directory shows the .pyc files to be slightly longer than their corresponding .py files. Are you out-clevering yourself, are you prematurely optimizing?

Comment: @msw, Weather its sensible is not the point ~ of course depends on the situation. One reason I asked the question is I wanted to know how easy it would be for a bad actor to embed/hide malicious code in a less obvious (non humanly readable) way. Of course one could just compress the code too, but smaller byte-code may be harder to detect. When auditing for malicious Python code, its useful to know what options are available and what malicious commands may look like. Further there would be some legitimate uses for this too. (where the overhead of compiling on the client is noticeable).

Comment: Exact use *was* important because we would have closed this question as too broad. Hiding your actual question was disingenuous at best.

Comment: @msw, I dont see how this is too broad, asking what is possible is valid, since I'm curious about the CPython runtime. There are multiple reasons I wanted to know, I just listed one of them above.

Comment: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: The question is practical and the answer is straightforward. Use `marshal.loads` and skip the first 12 bytes of a `pyc`. This is not vague or open-ended.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Is there a way to run the data from a pyc file directly?

The compiled code object can be saved using `marshal`

```
import marshal
bytes = marshal.dumps(eggs)
```

the bytes can be converted back to a code object

```
eggs = marshal.loads(bytes)
exec(eggs)
```

A `pyc` file is a marshaled code object with a header

For Python3, the header is 16 bytes which need to be skipped, the remaining data can be read via `marshal.loads`.

---

See [Ned Batchelder's blog post](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200804/the_structure_of_pyc_files.html):

> At the simple level, a .pyc file is a binary file containing only three things:
>
> - A four-byte magic number,
> - A four-byte modification timestamp, and
> - A marshalled code object.

---

Note, the link references Python2, but its almost the same in Python3, the `pyc` header size is just 16 instead of 8 bytes.

Comment: The result of `eggs` is a code object, not bytes you can read/write. Say I wan't to write eggs to a file or database, and load it later to execute.

Comment: spam is a string, but the question is asking about using the data from a pyc file. (bytecode, which doesn't have to be parsed & recompiled every time).

Comment: a string is bytes. If you want to avoid calling compile after loading the 'bytes', then you can just marshal the code object

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the platform of the compiled `.pyc` is correct, you can just import it. So with a file `bar.pyc` in the python path, the following works even if `bar.py` does not exist:

```
import bar
bar.call_function()
```

Comment: Yep, I was aware of this, see question **(without having the data on-disk necessarily)**

Comment: That part of your question wasn’t really clear… “the data” is quite ambiguous. You mean without having the `pyc` on the disk. You could just save the file temporarily to the current directory.

Comment: Yep, I was being intentionally ambiguous, to avoid answers focusing on the whichever method is used to read in the data bytes.